# Error al descargar zip desde PHP

Tags: php, zip, descarga

Buenas!

Estoy tratando de realizar una descarga de un archivo zip desde el servidor, pero al iniciar la descarga, se queda pegado terminando como fallida.

[image: Falla de la descarga]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-- **Como dato, cuando cambio el tipo de archivo a plain y descargo un 
txt cualquiera, lo descarga y abre sin problemas**--

Les dejo parte de mi código en donde gatillo la descarga.
(cambié los nombres para que se entienda mi problema)

```
   header('Content-Type: application/zip');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fotos.zip');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Content-Length: '.filesize('C:/ExportacionImagenes/CarpetaComprimida.zip'));

   readfile('C:/ExportacionImagenes/CarpetaComprimida.zip');
```

Comment: Puedes intentar remover esta linea `Content-Transfer-Encoding`  puedes comprobar que tu archivo existe, supongo que el real es dinamico

Comment: Así es, es dinámico. Primero creo el zip y luego realizo la descarga. Voy a intentara ver qué pasa, gracias.

Comment: Has revisado los logs? ¿queda alguna traza de error?

Comment: Si un txt si se descarga bien puede ser que el zip siga en uso, quiza, pueden intentar poner este ContentType `application/zip, application/octet-stream`

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que cuando el zip pesa menos de 50MB descarga sin problemas, pero pasando ese tamaño 100 MB o 200 MB arroja el error de descarga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No puedo comentar, así que lo pongo como respuesta.**

El cambio que has hecho a memory_limit tendrá un efecto más o menos grande dependiendo de donde lo hayas hecho. Este valor determina la máxima cantidad de memoria que puede usar un script. 
Si el valor lo has cambiado en el archivo php.ini de tú servidor, entonces afectará a todos los scripts php del mismo, por lo que sí hay muchas peticiones simultáneas, la memoria se puede agotar rápidamente sí los scripts usan mucha memoria.
Si el valor lo has cambiado en el propio script (usando ini_set) sólo afectará al propio script.

Normalmente suelo dejar un valor relativamente pequeño en la configuración del servidor, y sólo aumentar usando ini_set en aquellos scripts que lo necesiten.

Comment: Estimado, la modificación la hice en el php.ini en el servidor. Es una exportación de imágenes que solamente se usa una vez al mes, pero de todas formas voy a buscar modificar el valor de la forma que me indicas tú para evitar problemas. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Acabo de realizar la modificación con el ini_set y funciona sin problemas. Muchas gracias, estimado.

Comment: De nada. Me alegro que te haya funcionado. De paso, gracias por la edición de la respuesta. La escribí desde el móvil.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo resolví modificando el `memory_limit`. Estaba en `128M` y lo subí a `1280M` y descarga sin problemas. No sé bien cuales son las desventajas de haber modificado ese valor.